# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level django

Tags: django

The below code is showing an indentation error...please help!

```
def downtime_monitor():
        content = {'when':timezone.now(), 'name':'saumitra', 'back_up':backup}
        message = ''
        template = 'downtime_alert.html'
    to = '+91756785696'
        response = send_sms(to, message, content, template)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Python using indentation for blocks of code. The standard way is use 4 spaces for one block. In your code you have to write code like this:

```
def downtime_monitor():
    content = {'when':timezone.now(), 'name':'saumitra', 'back_up':backup}
    message = ''
    template = 'downtime_alert.html'
    to = '+91756785696'
    response = send_sms(to, message, content, template)
```

If you have still this error you have to check the row with the error and find the problem (probably mixed spaces and tabs). Some IDEs have a problems with mixing spaces and tabs and others will replace tabs for spaces automatically.